# How to start an app on the device with voice commands or by tapping on the icon in Android Wear Device?

Tags: wear-os

In Android Wear it shows the notification and we can reply back through wearable device.        **But how to start any app from the Wearable device like voice input("Ok Google") or tap on the icon. Action should start from the wearable device not from mobile.**

For Example  to start my mobile's camera through Android Wear Device i will give voice input as "start Camera" and camera should start.

Answer (score 1):

With the current preview-version of the SDK, this is not possible yet.

But looking at http://developer.android.com/wear/design/user-interface.html tells you, that this will possible using the "Cue Cards".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now! :)

With the release of the Wear SDK (API Level 20, Android 4.4W), you can now [develop Wear applications](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html) with very much the same stack as standard Android apps (i.e. Activities, Services, Layouts, Views, &c).

There is also an [API for communication](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html), which for example Google Play Music uses to control media playback from the watch.Therefore, you could develop an application, installed both in the Wear device and in the handheld, to launch the phone's camera when started (by sending the command from the Wear activity).